# What is wrong with my batch file code

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to find out why my file instantly exits when I open it.

Im trying to make a guess the number game.

```
@echo off
set morl="Between 1 and 100"
:menu
cls
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Instructions
set /p option=
if %option%==1 goto loop
if %option%==2 goto instructions
goto error
:error
cls
echo Enter 1 or 2
pause
goto menu
:instructions
cls
echo 1. Enter a number
echo 2. It will say higher or lower
echo 3. Repeat based on step 2
pause
:loop
cls
echo Loading...
set num=%random% 
if /i %num% GTR 10 goto loop
if /i %num% LSS 1 goto loop 
goto start 
:start
cls
echo The answer is %morl%
set /p input=
if %input%==%num% goto win
if %input% lss %num% set morl="higher"
if %input% gtr %num% set morl="lower"
goto start
:win
cls
echo You won! the answer was %num%
pause
goto menu
```

Comment: never coded in this language, so i will only guess that problem should be that you never called :menu

Comment: Remove `@echo off` for debugging!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call menu function

```
@echo off
set morl="Between 1 and 100"
goto menu
:menu
cls
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Instructions
set /p option=
if %option%==1 goto loop
if %option%==2 goto instructions
goto error
:error
cls
echo Enter 1 or 2
pause
goto menu
:instructions
cls
echo 1. Enter a number
echo 2. It will say higher or lower
echo 3. Repeat based on step 2
pause
:loop
cls
echo Loading...
set num=%random% 
if /i %num% GTR 10 goto loop
if /i %num% LSS 1 goto loop 
goto start 
:start
cls
echo The answer is %morl%
set /p input=
if %input%==%num% goto win
if %input% lss %num% set morl="higher"
if %input% gtr %num% set morl="lower"
goto start
:win
cls
echo You won! the answer was %num%
pause
goto menu
```